# Clip/Control scrolling of table view

Tags: ios, uitableview

Sorry: My problem is little lengthy and may be complicated:

I have a `UITableView` with a row section header view and a cell. There is a background image (blurred) on the whole `UITableView`. The image is visible from section header as well. And I achieved that by making background color of section header and cell to be `clearColor`. There is some text on the cell. When I scroll the cell, the text on cell gets into the section header as well (because section view is `clearColor`).

What I want is that the cell text should not be seen when entering into header section (It is same as if section header has non-clear color with alpha 1) but if I do that I cannot see my original background image from the section header view which I want to see.

How can I achieve this effect?  Is there a way to apply some kind of transparent mask on section header view so that the image below is visible but the text from cell is not seen on it when scrolling?

Comment: How have you set the image ??
Please show some code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely clear on how your UITableView is set up, but you could try the `masksToBounds` property of `CALayer`. Make sure you add the QuartzCore framework then import the header:

`#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"`

Then setting the `masksToBounds` property would look something like this:

`yourView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;`